# form submitted and same post being made twice..why is this occurring

Tags: python, django

Not sure what I did wrong. I'm making a commenting system that users can post comment on a post and be able to reply to that comment. Every thing works fine except when user reply to some comment that reply is being shown as a single comment.(and the it's shown as a reply as well) so if I reply to comment "how are you" with a message "good", then I have created two "good". one as the reply. one as the single comment. I've looked around my code, but I have no idea why this is happening. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you/.Here's my code.

views.py

```
def post(request, slug):
        user = get_object_or_404(User,username__iexact=request.user)
        try:
            profile = MyProfile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
            # if it's a OneToOne field, you can do:
            # profile = request.user.myprofile
        except MyProfile.DoesNotExist:
            profile = None


        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        post.views += 1  # increment the number of views
        post.save()      # and save it

        path = request.get_full_path()
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(path=path)
        #comments = post.comment_set.all()
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            parent_id = request.POST.get('parent_id')
            parent_comment = None
            if parent_id is not None:
                try:
                    parent_comment = Comment.objects.get(id=parent_id)
                except:
                    parent_comment = None
            comment_text = comment_form.cleaned_data['comment']
            new_comment = Comment.objects.create_comment(
                user=MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user),
                path=request.get_full_path(),
                text=comment_text,
                post = post,
                parent = parent_comment
                )

            comment_form = CommentForm()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())
        for c in comments:
            c.get_children()
        context_dict = {
            'post' :post,
            'profile' :profile,
            'comments' : comments,
            'comment_form':comment_form

        }

        return render(request, 'main/post.html', context_dict)
```

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
def get_children(self):
        if self.is_child:
            return None
        else:
            return Comment.objects.filter(parent=self)
```

post.html

```
<h1>Comments/Questions</h1>
<form method="POST" action=''>{% csrf_token %}
{{ comment_form.as_p }}
<input type='submit' class='btn btn-default' value='Add comment'/>
</form>


<br/>
<hr/>
<table class='table'>

{% for comment in comments %}

<tr><td>{{ comment.get_comment }} 
<br/><small>via {{ comment.user }} | {{ comment.timestamp|timesince }} ago </small>
        {% if not comment.is_child %}
        <ul>
        {% for child in comment.get_children %}
        <li>{{ child.get_comment }} 
        <small>via {{ child.user }}</small>


        </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <a href='#' class='reply_btn'>Reply</a>
        <div class='reply_comment'>
        <form method="POST" action=''>{% csrf_token %}
        <input type='hidden' name='parent_id' value='{{ comment.id }}' />
        {{ comment_form.as_p }}
        <input type='submit' class='btn btn-default' value='Add reply'/>
        </form>
        </div>
        {% endif %}


</td></tr>

{% endfor %}

</table>

</div>
```

And the comment is displayed in post.html and for that page, view is

```
def post(request, slug):
        user = get_object_or_404(User,username__iexact=request.user)
        try:
            profile = MyProfile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
            # if it's a OneToOne field, you can do:
            # profile = request.user.myprofile
        except MyProfile.DoesNotExist:
            profile = None


        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        post.views += 1  # increment the number of views
        post.save()      # and save it

        path = request.get_full_path()
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(path=path)
        #comments = post.comment_set.all()
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
        for c in comments:
                c.get_children()

        context_dict = {
            'post' :post,
            'profile' :profile,
            'comments' : comments,
            'comment_form':comment_form
        }
        return render(request, 'main/post.html', context_dict)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The duplicate comments are just a result of your template.
It is happening because when you loop through all comments, the newly made comment is included in the `comments` too.

Besides acting as a comment child, it is also a comment object and that is why it is included in `commments` when you `filter()` comments with a supplied path and then it is rendered in template as a normal comment object.

For fixing this, you need to use recursive tree. There are available django apps like `django-mptt` which comes handy in this type of issues.

After integration it into your comments model, you can simply use the `{% recursetree %}` templatetag to render comments without duplication.

Comment: I'm mainly following some tutorial, and he didn't do the recursetree but his code works....hmm so where should I use {% recursetree %}?

Comment: `{% recursetree %}` is part of `django-mptt`. For comments app, this http://martinfitzpatrick.name/article/django-threaded-comments/ might help

Comment: I'm sorry I think I misled you, I'm not trying to implement threaded comment.  I just want replying to a comment feature. not reply after reply after reply.....I think there's error in my code but just cant figure out what...

Comment: You can implement maximum replies in django-mptt.